# Recieving a 403 forbidden error when using latitude and longitude: geocoding

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, http-status-code-403, remote-server

Our site has the option to insert your postcode in,  which in turn works with geocoding to work out the latitude and longitude.

This code has not been changed for years but today if the user trys to insert a postcode or update it from yesterday or before the error 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.' pops up.

The requests have not shot past 2,500 so I cant see Google blocking us because of that..

Any ideas??

Comment: Confirming the same issue here. Just out of the blue started getting rejected about an hour ago.

Comment: How are you requesting the result?  Are you using a deprectated geocoding API that might have just been turned off?

Comment: You are correct, in my case I was using an outdated library using the v2 api

Answer (score 4):

The version 2 Geocoding API was turned off September 9th as announced...

From [Upgrading Your Geocoding API Application To v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodingupgrade?hl=en)

> Version 2 ("v2") of the Geocoding API was officially deprecated on 8 March 2010 and 
>   has now been turned down. As of 9 September 2013 the v2 API will no longer work.

Answer (score 0):

Copy of my answer to: [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807114/http-error-403-with-api-id-in-accessing-google-maps/19050707#19050707)

Api v2 was closed down on sept 13, 2013. Your question was asked on 14th - so that migh be a clue.
What I managed to do is simply modify URLs in `googlemaps.py`

I changed _DIRECTIONS_QUERY_URL (line 165 of googlemaps.py) to:

```
_DIRECTIONS_QUERY_URL = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/output?'
```

And it worked fine. 
Also I tried modiying line 164:    `_GEOCODE_QUERY_URL = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/output?'` as suggested [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests) but there's some error, and a) I don't need it anyway b) it's already covered by pygeocoder which is a bit more advanced that googlemaps.py

Comment: does it still works? I try e.g: `from googlemaps import GoogleMaps
gmaps = GoogleMaps(api_key)
destination = gmaps.latlng_to_address(38.887563, -77.019929)` and always end up with: `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden` the key I provide is valid.

Comment: It's not literally supposed to be "output", it should be either "json" or "xml", depending on what you want to use.