# Google maps API no longer working, trying js instead and failing

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been using the google map API for while, accessing via a url (see below), calling via simple_xml_load_file via php, parsing the xml, and storing the lat and long.  Simple.

URL for API call
http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?output=xml&key=some_key&q=12+main%2C+chicago%2C+Illinois

The process works when you add a new location to the database, if a user chooses to see a map, the coordinates are acquired via the above url in some php code.  I received an error today that is a 403 error.  I haven't changed my key, assuming that something else is up.

I my attempt to get this working again, I tried the new js API.  The problem with this is, at least to my understanding, I need to run it from a web page, accessing javascript, getting results.  This creates a problem for me as I do this all behind the scenes.  When I try a method to grab the data, I create a page that grabs the data, successfully, but this creates a header problem.

I don't care which way I use (old way or new but the old is just simpler for me).  I am looking for an understanding how others use the js API behind the scenes without header issues.  Since I am trying to do this fast I could very easily not be thinking of the best way to attack.  Also, if the "old" way still works but I need to change something, that would be awesome.

Quick explanation of "new" process on my site:

- User clicks on the map page.
- The code looks to see if the latitude and longitude are stored in the database.
- If not, it sends a curl request to a page to use the api 3 to get those values.
- Those values are then sent via ajax to another page to be stored
- The main code continues running, selecting the long and lat, while finding anything within x miles of that location, creating pins for those as well.

Call comes back with the header message for curl_exec...

```
$ch = curl_init();
$post_array = array(
    'e_id' => $this->getId(),
    'address' => $this->getAddress()
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, base_url() . 'establishment/google_map_processor');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_array));
curl_exec($ch);
```

I know, convoluted, but for how I am used to using the maps, I can't think of another way.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recieving a 403 forbidden error when using latitude and longitude: geocoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743128/recieving-a-403-forbidden-error-when-using-latitude-and-longitude-geocoding).  As announced v2 of the Google Maps Geocoding API has been turned off.  Maybe you should migrate to [v3 of the Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

Comment: Yes.  That's what I was trying to do when I started getting the header already sent issue since, at least to my knowledge, v3 can only be accessed via javascript.

Comment: It's version3 of the geocoding-API, not V3 of the Maps-Javascript-API. The Geocoding-APIV3 may be accessed without Javascript.