# 403 Forbidden error when geocoding

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I am running the following code

```
from googlemaps import GoogleMaps
gmaps = GoogleMaps('my api key here')
address = 'Constitution Ave NW & 10th St NW, Washington, DC'
lat, lng = gmaps.address_to_latlng(address)
print lat, lng
```

but when I run this I get the following error

```
  File "map.py", line 4, in <module>
lat, lng = gmaps.address_to_latlng(address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googlemaps-1.0.2-py2.7.egg/googlemaps.py", line 310, in address_to_latlng
return tuple(self.geocode(address)['Placemark'][0]['Point']['coordinates'][1::-1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googlemaps-1.0.2-py2.7.egg/googlemaps.py", line 259, in geocode
url, response = fetch_json(self._GEOCODE_QUERY_URL, params=params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googlemaps-1.0.2-py2.7.egg/googlemaps.py", line 50, in fetch_json
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 126, in urlopen
return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 406, in open
response = meth(req, response)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 444, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Any idea how to fix this error? I can't figure it out in any way.

Comment: Are you running this as a pure client or via some wamp server?

Comment: no wamp server...just running it through command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it turns out that Google Maps uses public IP. I was in a hackathon and some other participant had finished the quota blocking requests for everyone on that public IP.

Answer (score 0):

You can found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807114/http-error-403-with-api-id-in-accessing-google-maps/19050707#19050707) (second answer from furrypet). I simplified it a bit:

```
import urllib, json

def geocode(addr):
    url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%s&sensor=false" %   (urllib.quote(addr.replace(' ', '+')))
    data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    info = json.loads(data).get("results")[0].get("geometry").get("location")

    return info

address = 'Constitution Ave NW & 10th St NW, Washington, DC'

r = geocode(address)
print "%s %s" % (r['lat'], r['lng'])
```