# get coordinates with php

Tags: php, google-maps, coordinates

The following code should return with the coordinates of the place, but it returns with a comma only....

```
<?php

function getCoordinates($address){
$address = str_replace(" ", "+", $address);
$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=$address";
$response = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($response,TRUE);
return ($json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'].",".$json['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng']);
}


echo getCoordinates('740 Story Rd San Jose CA 95122');

?>
```

Comment: You are probably getting a [403 error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18743128/recieving-a-403-forbidden-error-when-using-latitude-and-longitude-geocoding/18745224#18745224)

Comment: Actually, you aren't getting an error, it seems to be working fine for me: http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=740%20Story%20Rd%20San%20Jose%20CA%2095122 Looks like the format of the returned data is not what your code is expecting.

Comment: Even if I change the url to the new one it comeswith a comma only. And the url works in the browser. Something should be wrong with the json?

Comment: You really should have put the information in your last comment in your original question.  Did this ever work?  Looks to me like your code doesn't take into account the asynchronous nature of the geocoder.

Comment: It did, I was not sure if I changed something while editing it, or it doesnt work any more.

Comment: So what can I do if it does not take into account the asynchronous nature of the geocoder. I am not sure what it means..

Comment: when you print `$json['status']`, what do you see?

Comment: Well while i was at work it started working again. :-/ What does it mean? Is it likely that it is going to stop again? Can I avoid it? Many thanks for your answers.

Comment: And it does not work again. Any idea what could I do?

Answer (score -2):

I have solved half of the problem:

{ "error_message" : "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.", "results" : [], "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" }

Because I had not set my API KEY i had limited access.

Can anyone show me how can i set my APIkey in php?